# Detect changes to a hidden input without a ID selector?

Tags: jquery

If you have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="one" value="20">
```

I'm struggling to get the right syntax to target it on changes, my attempt so far:

```
$(document).on("change", ($('input[name=one]').val()), someFunction);
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without event delegation if it exists when the document is ready.

```
$('input[name=one]').on('change', someFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! And what if you have multiple hidden inputs with different names that if changed should also trigger the function? With this method I'd have to have 10 different lines

Comment: @user2413333 you could use a selector to register for all hidden inputs: `input[type=hidden]`

Comment: Are they named similarly? If so you may be able to do something like `$('input[name^=in-common]').on('change', someFunction)` if they all start with "in-common". If you want to get all hidden input elements you can do like `$('form[name=foo] input:hidden').on('change', someFunction);`

Comment: Ah, I like the $('input[name^=in-common]').on('change', someFunction), however it's not working, and I think it's because the input name isn't changing, it's the value, do you know how I can add .val() in there?

Comment: The input name doesn't have to change. If the value changes they'd fire off. Here's a quick demo. http://jsbin.com/owoboh/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

It must be,

```
$(document).on("change", 'input[name=one]', someFunction);
```

It could also be,

```
$('input[name=one]').on("change", someFunction);
```

Or it can be,

```
$("parent of input").on("change", 'input[name=one]', someFunction);
```

`[]` used in a selector means you're trying to select an element with the attribute having a particular value. And you can't use  `$('input[name=one]').val()` in a selector, it won't work.

And if you have a bunch of `hidden` tags, you could use,

```
$(document).on("change", 'input[type=hidden]', someFunction);
```

In `someFunction` get the value of the `input` using `this.value`.